# Cookies Not Deleting in Asp.Net Core on Sign Out

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, cookies

I have been jumping through hoops trying to make sure my user is signed out. I'm running a Vue SPA with a connected API and Cookie Auth. The problem that I seem to have is that whatever I do my Cookies are just never being deleted or expired.

I've replaced all my calls to `signInManager.SignOutAsync()` with a shared `LogOutService` with a method that looks like this...

```cs
        public async Task LogOutAsync()
        {
            var context = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

            if (context == null)
            {
                await identityRepository.SignOutAsync();
                logger.LogInformation("User signed out with no context.");
            }
            else
            {
                var relevantCookies = context.Request.Cookies
                    .Where(c => 
                        c.Key.Contains(".AspNetCore.") || c.Key.Contains(".AspNet.") || c.Key.Contains("Microsoft.Authentication"));

                foreach (var cookie in relevantCookies)
                {
                    context.Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
                }

                await identityRepository.SignOutAsync();
                context.Session.Clear();
                logger.LogInformation("User signed out and cookies and session were cleared.");
            }
        }
```

I've followed the code through and it is executing as expected. I've tried replacing the Delete call with a creating a new, expired Cookie (which, internally is, I believe, what the Delete method does in Core anyway) and the results are the same.... nothing.

This ws all working fine before I migrated over to .net Core - just by calling `signInManager.SignOutAsync()`.

How am I able to log out the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the answer to this quite by accident.

In my code the method above was being called within a catch before throwing an exception.

If you delete the cookies then as soon as you throw an Exception then the Exception hijacks the entire response and all your nice cookie sets are lost.

If you need this to work then you need to not throw the exception (in my case I returned null from the method and logged an error manually instead).

This will apply to anything that intercepts and replaces the response such as custom middleware so if you have a similar issue there's a good place to start looking.